# How to make same js library work in both browser and react native?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, browser

I have a js library that I want to be usable both in the *browser* and *react native*. Most of the code is reusable, but some parts need platform conditioning. Something like:

```
if (react_native) { 
  do rn stuff 
} else { 
  do browser stuff 
}
```

I’ve seen flags like this used in open source projects but I’m not sure how to get access to them?

Comment: I never worked on react-native before. But I found [Platform](https://reactnative.dev/docs/platform-specific-code#platform-module) api. Looks like `Platform.OS` will be:  `ios` / `android` / `web` etc. which you can use in your condition?. Here is a [snack](https://snack.expo.io/@iamajeets/hello-world).

Comment: This works inside react native, but what what would if I run this in a reactjs app? Will it be just undefined?

Comment: Yes. That will be `undefined`. Can you share names of those open source libraries doing this? I would like to read them.

Comment: Assuming that you are coming up with a library, wont it be a problem when it comes to dependencies, like when you install to a web it will still install RN dependencies and vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

the global object `window` only exists in the browser environment so you can check to see if it is defined you are in a browser if not it can any other environment such as `react-native`, `node.js`, etc.